# Локализация botfront

Tags: git, github, meteor

Всем привет! Пытался локализировать на русский язык BotFront (https://github.com/botfront/botfront/tree/master). Все сделал как по инструкции, но почему-то когда я меняю что-то в файлах, даже иконки, то изменения не происходит.

Устанавливал следующим образом:

1. Установил Meteor

2. Клонировал репозиторий и установил туда метеор.

Я запускал и все корректно работает, но если я изменяю код, то ничего не меняется в интерфейсе. В чем может быть проблема?